From recurrence to general term formula.
If $$a_{n+1}+\frac{1}{a_n}=2$$,where $n\geq 1$,how to find out the general term of $a_n$?
By observation and guess, I have found two solutions :$a_n\equiv 1$ and $a_n=\frac{n+2}{n+1}$.
but I don't know how to solve it from the recurrence formula.

"By observation and guess", you could do much better: see the edit in the answer to the linked post.

One way would be to try to find a simple change variables to something with an easier recurrence. The solutions you found suggest $1$ as a limiting value for $a_n$, so writing the relation in terms of $a_n - 1$ gives
$$
a_{n+1} - 1 = \frac{a_{n} - 1}{(a_n - 1) + 1}.
$$
Taking the reciprocal of both sides then gives
$$
\frac{1}{a_{n+1} - 1} = \frac{1}{a_n - 1} + 1,
$$
which is of the form $x_{n+1} = x_n + 1$. So the general solution will be
$$
\frac{1}{a_{n} - 1} = \frac{1}{a_0 - 1} + n\Longrightarrow a_n = \frac{(n+1)a_0 -n }{n a_0 - (n-1)}
$$

Why not rather vote to close as a duplicate? (and if you think your solution adds something, post it rather over there)
